# how to live view in Titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy, tishadow

My team have been developing Titanium in the past few months, and now we are facing a problem: when we make changes on the View code(change its font, its background or size) , it takes a long time ( about 1 minute ) until we see the result displayed on device.  that is really a big waste of time.

I saw the [TiShadow](http://tishadow.yydigital.com/) already, it's great, but it only support js code( like  `Alloy.createTableList...` ), doesn't support the Alloy XML( I mean you can't see your changes displayed on the screen once change the .xml or .tss file )

I also checked 'forgedUI', but unfortunately it's just an UI design tool, and the bad news is its official website is shut down.

To reduce its compile time, I bought SSD disk for my team. The compile time indeed reduced from 60s to 40s. but it's still too long.

Is there any good tool that could make us debug the titanium faster?  or how to reduce Titanium's compile time?

Comment: Tishadow allow us "live view" our XML/tss files' changes. see my post below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am able to find following tools which are available for Titanium to reduce the time taken to test the application in device/simulator.

1. [TiShadow](http://tishadow.yydigital.com/) : Most widely used and open source.
2. [Rapiddev](http://appersonlabs.com/2014/01/09/rapiddev-titanium-development-speed-light/) : Currently only for ios but under rapid development.
3. [LiveView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/LiveView) : Available with enterprise version of Titanium.

*P.S : With TiShadow I was able to test changes made in tss/views along with controllers. Do monitor the terminal( from where tishadow command is triggered ) to see progress in re-compilation of code.*

Comment: for anyone stumbling upon this question now, LiveView is free and comes packaged with the free Appcelerator Studio.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATED at 2019-04-11:  don't use titanium, use React Native or Flutter.

I was wrong.

tishadow allow you to "live view" your Alloy XML/style file when changes.

just use:

```
$ ti build --platform android --target device --shadow
```

nothing else to do, you will see your app will launch , and every code you change, your app will reload automatically.

no more "$ tishadow server", no more "$ tishadow apply" ....

really great !