# Does exist any way to check quickly the layout (css/look and feel) in Titanium Studio, without run the app every time on device?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

As I wrote in the title, I'm wondering whether exists some solution to test layout without run the application on device, because it takes 30/45 sec to load itself on the device. I'm working on an iMac i7 with 8GB ram...

Comment: maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27936997/3419997) will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using a simulator/emulator, the best way is probably to use something like [TiShadow](http://tishadow.yydigital.com/). You can then see live updates on the device without having to rebuild.